# App force closes on a null pointer exception. Culprit is known but no solution

Tags: android, android-widget

Newbie here. I'm stumped with design because my app just FC's on start. I wanted to create a popup menu (PopupWindow with ListView) within an activity, which makes 2 XML's: One for my activity, and one for my dummy menu (menu_dummy.xml). Problem code right now looks like this:

```
...

    mSet = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mPopup = mSet.inflate(R.layout.menu_dummy, null, false);
    Resources base = getResources();
    ListView m = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
    String[] items = new String[]{base.getString(R.string.accounts), base.getString(R.string.about)};
    ArrayAdapter<String> lstItems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);
    m.setAdapter(lstItems);

...
```

When I execute my code, I find out that ListView m (menu_popup, under menu_dummy.xml) always returns null, despite it being registered in my R.java. Did I miss out on anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are inflating the layout but you are not using the inflated layout to get the reference to m. So Android is trying to find `menu_popup` in the current layout and hence returning null.

Change this section:

```
ListView m = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
```

to:

```
ListView m = (ListView)mPopup.findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
```

Now, you should get a reference to `menu_popup` which is under `menu_dummy` since you will be using the reference to the inflated `menu_dummy` stored in `mPopup`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
ListView m = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
```

with:

```
ListView m = (ListView)mPopup.findViewById(R.id.menu_popup);
```

Comment: Whew. Never thought of that. Actually I had a similar problem which goes back over a year already. Thanks a bunch.